# Set input value as a result of calculating three other input values in PHP

Tags: php, html

In a form, I would like to do math operations with the values entered in the following inputs:

```
    <?php
        function makeTextInputField($qnt_art) 
            $textqnt = ucfirst($qnt_art);       
            echo        
                <label for='{$qnt_art}'>Quantità Articolo:</br></label>
                <input type='integer' name='{$qnt_art}' value='' /input>
                </br></br>
    <?php
        function makeTextInputField($prz_unit) 
            $textprz = ucfirst($prz_unit);      
            echo        
                <label for='{$prz_unit}'>Prezzo Unità:</br></label>
                <input type='double' name='{$prz_unit}' value='' /input>
                </br></br>
    <?php
        function makeTextInputField($perc_sc) 
            $textperc = ucfirst($perc_sc);      
            echo        
                <label for='{$perc_sc}'>Sconto (decimali):</br></label>
                <input type='double' name='{$perc_sc}' value='' /input>
                </br></br>
```

Once the user has entered values into the above inputs, I'd like those values used in the following equation:

```
$imp_art=(($qnt_art)*($prz_unit))- ((($qnt_art)*($prz_unit))*$perc_sc)
```

...and for the result of that equation to assigned to `$imp_art` in the following code, without having to press an "edit" button:

```
    <?php
        function makeTextInputField($imp_art) 
            $textimp = ucfirst($imp_art);       
            echo        
                <label for='{$imp_art}'>Importo Articolo/i:</br></label>
                <input type='double' name='{$imp_art}' value=''/input>
                </br></br>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should do it in javascript, if you need to change it in client side immediately. Also, you need to put the php close tag `?>` and the function open tag`{` and close tag`}`. when you echo the html, please quote the html. e.g. `echo '<label for="{$imp_art}">>Importo Articolo/i:</br></label>';`

Comment: i've tried to write as your exemple, but it keep showing on post the close tags, the quotes, and all the semicolons. idk, the way i've compiled works whitout problems, maybe it's a notepad ++ problem? pls help...

Comment: that is not notepad ++ problem. it may cause by your code. did you run your php code through apache??

Comment: can you provide more code in http://pastebin.com/ which i can help you easily.

Comment: yes i've enabled apache on xampp and on config it browse php

Comment: how can i send you the pastebin?

Comment: put the link in the comment

Comment: http://pastebin.com/163d5YFe

Comment: Please follow my instruction that i mention function need `{` `}` ***brackets*** and the html that you echo which need `"` `"` ***quote***. Also if you do not open short tag in apache, please use `<?php` not `<?` In pastebin, you are wrong in `<?phpmakeDateInputField('data:');
?>`. must be `<?php makeDateInputField('data:'); ?>` ***ALSO PUT THE CLOSE TAG IN EACH PHP CALLING***

Comment: Do it like this. http://pastebin.com/vh5vUGNY

Comment: ok, i do exactly what you said but it keep showing ";}?> before every label title except for first.

Comment: please leave a pastebin after you edit

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0iyXRhuQ

Comment: You cannot declare a function more than once!! `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare makeTextInputField() (previously declared in /0iyXRhuQ.php:33) in /0iyXRhuQ.php on line 63.` You should do like this: http://pastebin.com/kYc4Brek

Answer (score 0):

1.As Jacky Shek metioned, you have to correct the basic syntax first, like close php tag.

2.How do you know the user has typed the values for: '$qnt_art', '$prz_unit' and '$perc_sc'?

So you have to listen the change event for all three inputs , eg:

```html
<input type='integer' name='{$qnt_art}' value='' onchange="validate()"/>
```

3.You definitely need a function to validate the input value with JavaScript.

```js
function validate(){
   if($qnt_art && $prz_unit && $perc_sc){//your check logic
      //change the text of imp_art.
   }
}
```

4.How to check that the user has finished input? If he want to type "123" for $qnt_art, do you calculate when he type "1" or "12"? So maybe you need a delayed check.

```js
function delayCheck(){
  if(!this.lastTime){
    this.lastTime = new Date().getTime();
    this.timer = setTimeout(validate, 100);//delay 100ms to check
  }else{
    if(new Date().getTime() - this.lastTime < 100){
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.timer = setTimeout(validate, 100);//delay 100ms to check
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i will to do the math operation only when the fieds are not null? isn't easier? i explain, the $qnt_art (article quantity) should be not null, $prz_art (prize per single article) should be not null, and $perc_sc (discount in decimals) should be not null or 0.0, so what if i set the operation when the fields are not null, and how it could be done if it's possible ?

Comment: @DanieleMarchese If you insist doing the math operation in php, please use jquery ajax with the onchange event. also fix your php coding first.

Comment: @DanieleMarchese I think it's not a hard work to determine whether or not a input component is empty.This logic should be in my validate function.Unless you aren't familar with javascript.

Comment: no, sorry,  i'm not familiar with javascript, as i said i'm here to learn, in fact i'm searching for tutorials and other lessons! if somone show me some examples of the way i could use and the syntax of math operations i could try to adapt it on my own. not a copy/paste solution obv.